# Why does the Blonde forget about her earring?

Tags: plot-explanation, following

In *Following* (1998), how come The Blonde gives up so easily when Cobb doesn't tell her where he put her earring? There is no excuse for Cobb to not tell her and teasing is not acceptable for a long period since it's a valuable item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the directorial debut of [Memento 2001](https://chrisnolan.fandom.com/wiki/Memento_(Film)) and [Batman Begins 2005](https://chrisnolan.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Begins_(Film)) director
[Christopher Nolan](https://chrisnolan.fandom.com/wiki/Christopher_Nolan_Wiki), ["Following 1998",](https://chrisnolan.fandom.com/wiki/Following_(Film))

[The character of the "attractive" blonde](https://chrisnolan.fandom.com/wiki/The_Blonde) is from the start, intimately involved with [the thief, Cobb.](https://chrisnolan.fandom.com/wiki/Cobb) As a co-conspirator, she has no reason to suspect that her opportunities to retrieve the earring will be numbered thus it is not a priority.

To make the earring retrieval a low priority is probably a twofold mechanism used by the director,

1. it is an implication of trust consciously laid out by the director, and
2. it is a vehicle used to drive the impact of the less than stellar [MacGuffin](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MacGuffin) - which was displayed early on - and then repeatedly thereafter:

That Cobb cannot be trusted by *anyone*.

Had the blonde distrusted Cobb too thoroughly, it is unlikely the final twist would have had any impact.